# Attempt to apply redactions results in exception

Tags: itext, redaction

I have followed the steps to create annotations and apply redaction using iText 5.5.9.  Here is my code:

```
using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(newFilePath, FileMode.Create)))
{
    // Redact the values.
    var pdfAnot1 = new PdfAnnotation(stamper.Writer, new Rectangle(165f, 685f, 320f, 702f));
    pdfAnot1.Title = "First Page";
    pdfAnot1.Put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, PdfName.REDACT);
    pdfAnot1.Put(PdfName.IC, new PdfArray(new[] { 0f, 0f, 0f }));
    pdfAnot1.Put(PdfName.OC, new PdfArray(new[] { 1f, 0f, 0f })); // red outline
    stamper.AddAnnotation(pdfAnot1, 1);
    for (var i = 1; i <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
    {
        var pdfAnot2 = new PdfAnnotation(stamper.Writer, new Rectangle(220f, 752f, 420f, 768f));
        pdfAnot2.Title = "Header";
        pdfAnot2.Put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, PdfName.REDACT);
        pdfAnot2.Put(PdfName.IC, new PdfArray(new[] { 0f, 0f, 0f }));
        pdfAnot2.Put(PdfName.OC, new PdfArray(new[] { 1f, 0f, 0f })); // red outline
        stamper.AddAnnotation(pdfAnot2, i);
    }

    var cleaner = new PdfCleanUpProcessor(stamper);
    cleaner.CleanUp();
}
```

However, I always receive the following exception on PdfCleanUpProcessor construction:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>        at
>   iTextSharp.xtra.iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpProcessor.ExtractLocationsFromRedactAnnots(Int32 page, PdfDictionary pageDict)
>      at
>   iTextSharp.xtra.iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpProcessor.ExtractLocationsFromRedactAnnots()
>   at
>   iTextSharp.xtra.iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpProcessor..ctor(PdfStamper pdfStamper)

It appears that there is a null reference produced in extractLocationsFromRedactAnnots on the assignment of annotDict, so the next line throws the exception:

```
    /**
     * Extracts locations from the redact annotations contained in the document and applied to the given page.
     */
    private IList<PdfCleanUpLocation> ExtractLocationsFromRedactAnnots(int page, PdfDictionary pageDict) {
        List<PdfCleanUpLocation> locations = new List<PdfCleanUpLocation>();

        if (pageDict.Contains(PdfName.ANNOTS)) {
            PdfArray annotsArray = pageDict.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);

            for (int i = 0; i < annotsArray.Size; ++i) {
                PdfIndirectReference annotIndirRef = annotsArray.GetAsIndirectObject(i);
                PdfDictionary annotDict = annotsArray.GetAsDict(i);
                PdfName annotSubtype = annotDict.GetAsName(PdfName.SUBTYPE);

                if (annotSubtype.Equals(PdfName.REDACT)) {
                    SaveRedactAnnotIndirRef(page, annotIndirRef.ToString());
                    locations.AddRange(ExtractLocationsFromRedactAnnot(page, i, annotDict));
                }
            }
        }

        return locations;
    }
```

Any idea why this is happening?  An example PDF is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz0Wye-k7GsZUXdKbWtMTUNpcXc/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: *If you need an example PDF, please let me know.* - Yes, please supply a sample to reproduce the issue. This is usually done by publicly sharing a document on dropbox or googledrive and posting the URL here.

Comment: I added a link to an example PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues at work here, one being in the OP's code and one in iText(Sharp).

### Issue in the OP's code

One has to be aware that the architecture of the `PdfReader`/`PdfStamper` pair is not that of a document in memory that is manipulated only to be saved in the end. Instead manipulations by the stamper usually are written to the output stream as soon as possible and are not necessarily visible to other code working on the stamper.

The rationale is that the iText architecture (as wild as it may seem in versions before 7.x) is built to allow operations with a low resource footprint. In server applications which may have to process many PDFs in parallel this is very important.

In the case at hand the OP's code first adds **Redact** annotations and in the same run tries to cleanup using these annotations. This does not work. Instead  the OP either should add the annotations in one pass and apply cleanup in a second, i.e.

```
using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(source))
using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(temp, FileMode.Create)))
{
    // ... add REDACT annotations
}

using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(temp))
using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create)))
{
    var cleaner = new PdfCleanUpProcessor(stamper);
    cleaner.CleanUp();
}
```

or not use **Redact** annotations at all: After all, why add annotations only to immediately remove them again. For this `PdfCleanUpProcessor` has a second constructor which is given the cleanup locations directly:

```
/**
 * Creates a {@link com.itextpdf.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpProcessor} object based on the
 * given {@link java.util.List} of {@link com.itextpdf.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpLocation}s
 * representing regions to be erased from the document.
 *
 * @param pdfCleanUpLocations list of locations to be cleaned up {@see PdfCleanUpLocation}
 * @param pdfStamper          A{@link com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper} object representing the document which redaction
 *                            applies to.
 */
public PdfCleanUpProcessor(IList<PdfCleanUpLocation> pdfCleanUpLocations, PdfStamper pdfStamper)
```

### Issue in iText(Sharp)

The `PdfCleanUpProcessor` has a member dictionary `clippingRects` to which **Redact** annotation areas are added by their index in their page **Annots** array:

```
private IList<PdfCleanUpLocation> ExtractLocationsFromRedactAnnot(int page, int annotIndex, PdfDictionary annotDict) {
    ...
    clippingRects.Add(annotIndex, markedRectangles); 
    ...
}
```

If a document on multiple pages has **Redact** annotations with the same index in their respective page **Annots** array, therefore, this method in different calls tries to add multiple entries to the member `clippingRects` using the same key. The .Net `Dictionary` class does not allow this and throws an exception.

Thus, iTextSharp redaction by **Redact** annotations only works properly for a document with only **Redact** annotations if there only one page is so annotated!

The original development of this feature takes place in Java, and in Java `clippingRects` is a `HashMap` which allows overwriting entries, so no exceptions are thrown here. Furthermore, as the contents of `clippingRects` are used only in a special case (the use of **RO** or **OverlayText** in the **Redact** entries), the wrong entries often don't do any harm and, therefore, may not yet have been reproducibly observed.

Comment: Thanks @mkl, I agree that creating cleanup locations and using the alternate constructor is the way to go for my application.  However, the result is another exception: A Graphics object cannot be created from an image that has an indexed pixel format.

Comment: Unfortunately iTextSharp does not understand all bitmap formats in PDFs, but for redaction it needs to understand all image formats of images in the redacted area. The iTextSharp code probably should be hardened against such issues somewhat...

Comment: A followup on my previous exception.  The exception occurred on a document that did not conform to the same base format as the example document I included.  When processing PDF files of the correct form, as in the example, this solution works well.  Thanks @mkI!